# git-svn from the point of view of a git native user

Tags: git, git-svn

Are there any tutorials for git-svn *from the native git user's perspective*? My new workplace uses svn; I know git, and would like to continue using the branching and rebase workflow I am comfortable with, while eventually committing to svn repos. All of the tutorials for git-svn I can find are from the point of view of people switching *to* git from svn, which is not exactly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is the chapter [8.1 Git and Other Systems - Git and Subversion](http://git-scm.com/book/ch8-1.html) in Pro Git book, written by Scott Chacon.